# Media Library search functionality shows only on blank image fields

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library

We are using Sitecore 8.2 Initial Release for one of customer.

We have one simple question about the media library search. Whenever we click on browse button to select an image (when image field is empty), all the images and media files are displayed in search as shown in following screen shot.

[image]

However whenever an image field has an image, and if I try to browse button, only the selected image is displayed in search and I am unable to search for any another image. As shown in following screen shot.

[image]

Let me know if it works in media library search functionality like this?

Answer (score 3):

We had also this issue in past and we have talked to Sitecore. This is the bug in this revision. Try to upgrade to Sitecore 8.2 Update 3 that has this issue fixed.

Please review the release notes for Sitecore 8.2 Update 3 for reference number 94870 (this was provided by Sitecore) on https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update3/Release%20Notes

Comment: I have tried on this Update 3 version and it seems to be working. Thanks Rohit Chopra